# c# field is never assigned to and will always have its default value null?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, compiler-errors

C# Inhertance. I's trying to inherit class quadrilateral to class sqaure. I am unable to figure this out and I got the following error and I dont know what it means. Field square.p1 is never assigned to and will always have its default value null?

```
    using System;

    class testquadrilaterals 
    {
        static void Main() 
{
    quadrilateral obj1 = new quadrilateral(1.1, 1.2, 6.6, 2.8, 6.2, 9.9, 2.2, 7.4);
    obj1.printcoordinates();
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    square obj2 = new square( 4.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0 );
    obj2.printsquare();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
    }

    class point 
    {
        private double x;
private double y;

public point(double x_coord, double y_coord)
{
    x = x_coord;
    y = y_coord;
}

public double X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
public double Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }

public override string ToString()
{
    return ("(" + X + ", " + Y + ")");
}
    }

    class quadrilateral
    {
point p1, p2, p3, p4;

public quadrilateral(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
    double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)
{
    p1 = new point(x1, y1);
    p2 = new point(x2, y2);
    p3 = new point(x3, y3);
    p4 = new point(x4, y4);
}

public point P1 { get { return p1; } set { p1 = value; } }
public point P2 { get { return p2; } set { p2 = value; } }
public point P3 { get { return p3; } set { p3 = value; } }
public point P4 { get { return p4; } set { p4 = value; } }

public void printcoordinates()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Coordinates of Quadrilateral: \n" + p1.ToString() + " " + p2.ToString() + " " + p3.ToString() + " " + p4.ToString() + " ");
}
    }


    class square : quadrilateral
    {
point p1, p2, p3, p4;

public square(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,
    double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4) : base (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4)
{ }

public void printsquare()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Coordinates of Square: \n" + p1.ToString() + " " + p2.ToString() + " " + p3.ToString() + " " + p4.ToString() + " ");
    Console.WriteLine("Area: " + area());
   // Console.WriteLine("Sides: " + sides());
}

public double area() 
{

    return Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X) * Math.Abs(p1.Y - p3.Y); 
}
// public double sides() { }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

In this case the class `square` defines 4 fields which it never sets: p1, p2, p3 and p4

```
class square : quadrilateral {
  point p1, p2, p3, p4;

  ...
}
```

These fields are private and never set hence they are essentially useless as is.  The C# compiler is alerting you to this because this is usually an indication of a bug.

In this case it looks like you may have intended for `square` to simply use the values in `quadrilateral`.  The fields have the same name and type and there is an inheritance relationship between the two types.  If that's the case you should delete the fields in `square` and change the accessibility to `protected` in `quadrilateral`

```
class quadrilateral {
  protected  point p1, p2, p3, p4;
  ...
}
```

This will allow `square` to access the values

Answer (score 0):

If you are inheriting from quadrilaterial you don't need to define the variables p1/p2/p3/p4 again in square, you will inherit them from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

In Square::area(), the p1s and p2s are referring to those defined within the square class, not those in the quadrilateral class. You have both square::p1, square::p2, etc. and quadrilateral ::p1, quadrilateral::p2, etc. The square p1s and p2s are never assigned to. To have your square class use the quadrilateral class' p1s and p2s, don't redefine them in square.